# Django - In a survey app that uses forms is it necessary to use Formsets?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm currently working with a survey app. The answers are stored in a table created by a very simple model:

```
class Answer(models.Model): 
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name = "question", on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True)
        answer = models.TextField()
```

So for example, if the survey has 10 questions, 10 rows would be created in the database for each user.

Given the above, the form to be created must have multiple questions and the corresponding inputs to answer.

My questions are:

**1.** For these cases it is obligatory to use formsets?

**2.** If it is not mandatory, is it recommended? or is there a better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: If you really want a generic answer: it is never _mandatory_ to use forms (and formsets if you have multiple instances of a same form), but it is indeed recommended. Now whether you want formsets here really depends on how your front-end is supposed to work... (if you're to display all questions in a single form then you probably want formsets).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, I use a single form because all questions are loaded on one page and at the end the user presses the submit button.